# Where is the potential energy due to internal interactions in total energy?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, potential-energy

In thermodynamics the total energy of a system consists of kinetic energy of motion of the system as a whole, potential energy of the system as a whole due to *external* force fields, and energy contained within the system known as internal energy,
$$
    E = E_{\mathrm{k}} + E_{\mathrm{p}} + U \, . \tag{1}
$$

That is the way it is said in many books, lecture notes and online source. For instance, the first paragraph of [Wikipedia article on internal energy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_energy) says:

> In thermodynamics, the *internal energy* is one of the two cardinal
>   state functions of the state variables of a thermodynamic system. It
>   *refers to energy contained within the system, and excludes kinetic
>   energy of motion of the system as a whole, and the potential energy of
>   the system as a whole due to external force fields*. It keeps account
>   of the gains and losses of energy of the system.

Well, if a system is just one macroscopic body, I have no problems with these definition. But what if we have more than one body in our system?

Consider, for instance, an isolated system composed of two bodies of mass $m_{1}$ and $m_{2}$. According to classical mechanics, between two masses there always always exists a gravitational force
$$
    F = \frac{G m_{1} m_{2}}{r_{12}^2} \, ,
$$
and there exist a gravitational potential energy 
$$
    V = - \frac{G m_{1} m_{2}}{r_{12}} \, ,
$$
due to this interaction.

Now, this potential energy $V$ is not a part of $E_{\mathrm{p}}$ in (1), since it is not due to external, but rather internal force field.
Clearly, it is also not a part of $E_{\mathrm{k}}$.

Where is it then? **Is it included into internal energy $U$ or it is just an additional term for the total energy that has nothing to do with internal energy $U$?**

In other words, **the increase in which quantity (according to the 1st law of thermodynamics) is equal to the heat supplied to the system plus the work done on it: internal energy counted with or without this potential energy $V$ due to gravitational interaction?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In principle, the gravitational potential energy should be included into total internal energy, but in practice, most often it is not. I know of two reasons.

- because for systems that are discussed in thermodynamics, it is believed that gravitational energy is negligible compared to electromagnetic potential energy of the constituting particles;
- because it is difficult to include $1/r^2$ forces such as electromagnetic or gravitational force to calculations based on standard statistical physics in a unique and convincing way.

Comment: Regarding the second point, does it mean that when in statistical mechanics we write down internal energy as the weighted sum of all microstate energies $U = \sum_{i=1}^N p_i E_i$ the potential energy due to macroscopic interactions is actually already ignored?

Comment: When considering the heat gained by astrophysical systems due to gravitational collapse, we certainly don't ignore that energy.

Comment: @Wildcat, no, in principle the determination of $E_i$ can take into account interactions.

Answer (score 3):

Your separation into *potential energy of the system as a whole due to external force fields* and *energy contained within the system known as internal energy* seems a bit arbitrary. Still, if you want to split the PE up this way gravitational interactions within the system would have to go into internal energy.

Take the Solar System as an example. Everything in the Solar System sits within the gravitational field of the Milky Way, so you could assign a potential energy due to the external gravitational field of the Milky Way. However there's obviously also the potential energy due to the mutual gravitational attraction of the Sun, planets etc. You would have to treat this as internal energy.

Then you've got the potential energy of the Moon within the Earth's gravitational field, the potential energy of all the rock that went into making up the Earth and so on.

I guess splitting up the different effects can be useful - we don't consider the gravitational field of the Milky Way when calculating trajectories of spacecraft. But the splitting can be done in loads of different ways depending on what particular aspect of the Solar System you're looking at.

Comment: His choice of "splitting" as you call it is a little odd for such a simple system, but is a good exercise for understanding the broader concept of binding energy. Once he understands the concepts in play here he can apply them to [less trivial cases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_binding_energy#Derivation_for_a_uniform_sphere).

Comment: I rewrote the question. Now it is the following. When the first law refers to internal energy as a state function increase in which is equal to heat supplied to the system plus work done on it, does this state function include potential energy due to gravitational interactions within the system?

Answer (score 2):

The [gravitational potential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_potential) for particle 1 is $V_1(r_{12}) = -Gm_2/r_{12}$ and for particle 2 it is $V_2(r_{12}) = -Gm_1/r_{12}$. $m_2$ is in $V_1$ and vice versa because the gravitational potential energy is the potential energy in a gravitational field *per unit mass*, and therefore only depends on the mass that is generating that gravitational field. When you multiply by mass to go from gravitational potential to potential energy, you get the result you have above. I'm just clarifying by own notation of $V$ which is different from yours.

> Is it included into internal energy U

The "internal potential" energy as you seem to think about it is called the [gravitational binding energy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_binding_energy)), and is defined as being the answer to the following question : How much energy would I gain if I break up your system by separating the masses by an infinite distance ? This is equivalent to wondering how much energy it would take to transport $m_1$ to infinity while holding $m_2$ fixed, where the internal energy is the opposite of this amount (we could do it the other way around by switching $m_1$ and $m_2$ and get the same answer) :

\begin{eqnarray}
U_{grav} &=& m_1 \times V_1(r_{12}) - m_1 \times \underbrace{V_1(\infty)}_0 \\
 &=& -G m_1 m_2/r_{12}
\end{eqnarray}

Once $m_1$ is at $\infty$, it takes $0$ work to move $m_2$ to $\infty$ as well. The fact that the answer is negative is just telling you that you would actually lose energy by breaking up the system, and gain energy by forming it. Hope this helps. Let me know if you have any questions.

If you had two blobs of matter with masses $m_1$ and $m_2$ then their internal *thermodynamic* energy $U_{thermo}$ is not affected by any of this. The total energy is then :

$$
E_{tot} = E_k + E_p + U_{thermo} + U_{grav}
$$

So your equation $(4)$ is the correct one. Whether this means that the total internal energy is $U + V$ or just $U$ depends on how you define internal energy, but given the Wikipedia definition :

> It refers to energy contained within the system, and excludes kinetic energy of motion of the system as a whole, and the potential energy of the system as a whole due to external force fields. It keeps account of the gains and losses of energy of the system.

It therefore refers to $U + V$. The definition explicitly states that only potentials due to **external** force fields are excluded, not the internal ones as well as you have written.

Comment: Hmmm... The definition of internal energy which you give is surprising for me. In classical thermodynamics internal energy is just a state function the increase in which for a closed system during a thermodynamic process is equal to the heat supplied to the system plus the work done on the system. From a microscopic point of view of statistical thermodynamics it is the kinetic energy of particles motion and potential energy due to all kinds of interaction between particles in a system.

Comment: @BMS You've misunderstood what I'm doing here. The $U$ I gave is indeed the binding energy of both particles. Once the first mass is at $\infty$, you can take the other one to $\infty$ with $0$ work. I'm using [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_potential) definition of gravitational potential.

Comment: @Wildcat You're right, but the closest equivalent in your system is the binding energy (its opposite actually). See my edit. This is a simple 2 particle system, so it makes no sense to invoke notions of statistical physics to describe it.

Comment: @BMS Is that -1 from you ? The derivation is perfectly correct. You shouldn't down vote on a hunch just because you think I *might* have only treated the case for one mass. I haven't.

Comment: @BMS Care to +1 me then ? :P

Comment: @ticster I'm talking about a thermodynamic system, which is macroscopic by definition. It is not a two particle system, rather it consists of myriads of particles in two macroscopic pieces of bulk matter. And these pieces interact with each other thorough gravity.

Comment: @Wildcat Fine then, in that case, just add a term to your total energy called $U_{binding}$ whose value I've described above. I'll add some explanations in an edit.

Comment: @ticster I'm not a physicist, but I have a feeling that your very last equation is right. Then, however, there is a problem with thermodynamic notion of internal energy as I know it, which refers to energy contained within the system, and excludes kinetic energy of motion of the system as a whole, and the potential energy of the system as a whole due to external force fields.

Comment: @ticster this phrase can be found in many books on thermodynamics. But it is wrong for a system consisting of more than 1 macroscopic body, since there is a potential energy due to gravitational interaction of the bodies which is not counted according to this definition at all. Unless this energy is part of internal energy.

Comment: In other words, intuition tells me that gravitational (or any other kind of) interaction between macroscopic  bodies in a thermodynamic system does not contribute to its internal energy (at least in thermodynamic meaning of these quantity). But I could not find information about it in books.

Comment: @Wildcat You're right that the gravitational interactions between the 2 blobs does not contribute to its *thermodynamic* energy, it contributes to its *binding* energy. Which contributions we can call internal is just a semantics argument, but it's not unusual to refer to both as internal energies. It's just a question of definition at this point. The answer in its current form perfectly summarizes everything you need to know about the energy content of such a system.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15857/discussion-between-wildcat-and-ticster).